# How to fix Android emulator not responding after launch behaviour?

Tags: android

The below is the displayed output in the console:

> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] ------------------------------
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] Android Launch!
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] adb is running normally.
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] Performing 
>   net.learn2develop.Activities.ActivitiesActivity activity launch
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] Automatic Target Mode: launching
>   new emulator with  compatible AVD 'andy2'
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:37 - Activities] Launching a new emulator with
>   Virtual Device 'andy2'
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:38 - Emulator]
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:38 - Emulator] This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it  in an unusual way.
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:38 - Emulator] Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>
> [2011-08-10 15:59:40 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8

I am getting this error regularly. Please help me out of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Android 3.1 emulator is near useless and non-functional.

If you want to test your app > 2.3 then you will likely need to buy a device.

If you don't need your app to run on greater than 2.3 then change your emulator version to 2.3.3

check tools.android.com for up and coming hardware acceleration which will allow emulation of 3.0 onwards.

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me.

1. Open `AVD Manager`
2. `Show Advanced Settings`
3. Choose `Cold boot` from Boot option.

Force quit your `Emulator`, and run again.

Comment: My emulator got frozen. This approach worked for me, but I had to close the emulator first before doing the cold boot.

Comment: I just chose `Cold Boot` and it worked

Answer (score 7):

Lower the ram size to 512 or 256 MB as there must be a problem allocating the memory to the emulator.

Comment: I wish I could give this a million upvotes. I've had trouble with the emulators ever since repairing my system and had no clue why. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Lower the "Device ram size" under "Hardware" to 512 instead of 1024 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Close the emulator and open the AVD manager, select the pencil icon for the emulator device, click show advanced details when the pencil icon opens up and then select cold boot under boot options and load the emulator again this should work, just tried it now

Answer (score 1):

Go to

1. `C:\Users\PC_NAME\.android\avd\Yours_Phone.avd`
2. There you will find a file named `config.ini`.Open it in notepad
3. Inside this file you will find something like `hw.ramSize = 1536` here decrease the ramsize to 512 like `hw.ramSize = 512` and restart your emulator again. Hope everything will works fine

Answer (score 0):

Cold Boot worked for me, but it took me a bit of time to find where the option is.
Tools > Device Manager (opens the panel on the right)
Then you need to click on the little triangle to open the drop-down menu to do Cold Boot.

[screenshot showing where cold boot is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zMaR.png)

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem with this, I run Android emulator successfully but not response any more.
I run android studio and select the run Android Virtual Device Manager to select the current emulator
Click the right bottom menu and select "Cold boot now", it worked for me.
Good luck

Answer (score -1):

These steps worked for me

- Close The Emulator
- Open **`Device Manager`** in the right of Android Studio
- Select the emulator and then select the **drop down** arrow
- Select `Cold Boot Now`